# Show valid JSON array from query

Tags: arrays, json, codeigniter

I have a function to show a JSON array containing multiple registration id and data. I am using CodeIgniter. I tried to use notification using [this library](https://github.com/antongorodezkiy/codeigniter-gcm/).

```
public function send_notification($id_user, $message) {
  if ($this->muser->cek_follower($id_user) == TRUE) {
    $query = $this->muser->get_list_follower($id_user);
    $feedback['registration_id'] = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
      $query_list_user = $this->muser->get_all_name_user_from_id($row->id_follower);
      if ($query_list_user->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query_list_user->row();
        $response= $row->regid;
      } else {
        $feedback = 0;
      }
      array_push($feedback, $response);
    }
    $feedback['data'] = $message;
    echo json_encode($feedback);
  } else {
    $feedback = 0;
    echo json_encode($feedback);
  }
}
```

I tried GET from [this url](http://test.com/LagiDimana/index.php/user/send_notification/12/ada), but the output is like this

```
{
    "0": "XX3",
    "1": "XX4",
    "2": "XX2",
    "registration_id": [],
    "data": "ada"
}
```

How to make an output like this?

```
{
    "registration_id": [
        "XX3",
        "XX4",
        "XX2"
    ],
    "data": "ada"
}
```

I have tried and tried. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pushing `$response` data directly to the parent array `$feedback`, instead of actually pushing it to `$feedback['registration_id`].

So; replace this:

```
array_push($feedback, $response);
```

with this:

```
array_push($feedback['registration_id'], $response);
```